# Error while installing any libraries in ArcGIS Pro Python notebook

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, geopandas, numpy

I'm trying to install libraries,

[image: Library error in ArcGIS Pro Python notebook]

but the same error is shown for all library installation.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to include the error message as text. Images are not legible on all devices and can't be searched by others with the same issue.

Comment: Numpy is a included with ArcGIS Pro Python so no need to install that.  As far as the other libraries go - the ArcGIS Pro Python environment is locked and you cannot install any third-party libraries without first cloning the Python environment.  Also, see here for  clues on the assertion error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600426/whats-does-assert-sre-magic-magic-sre-module-mismatch-assertionerror-sre-m.

Comment: The issue is, geopandas library is working just fine in jupyter notebook of ArcGIS Pro but no within the ArcGIS Pro python notebook(within the software) .